# Low FPS and Constant Crashes when loading Worlds on IdeaPad 3 15IIL05 on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: graphics, lenovo, intel, minecraft, 23.10

Recently, a friend of mine switched to Linux but has been plagued with lower FPS (~30) and freezing when loading worlds in Lunar Client. I have tried updating and all the usual things, but am stuck on how to help him. I use Arch Linux, so I am not super familiar with Ubuntu. All help would be appreciated!

Specs:
8gb RAM
Intel Core i3-1005G1
Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 (integrated)
SSD